# Patterns for decorating private methods of a class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

In the below class I have a public method called ProcessMessage. This method is responsible for processing the incoming messages. Processing a message involves different stage. I want to decorate this class in such a way that I can publish performance counter values from each stage of the message processing.

I know I can override the ProcessMessage method and rewrite the logic once again with publishing performance counter values. But is there any better way / pattern which I can apply, so that I don’t have to duplicate the logic once again in the decorated class.

```
public class MessageProcessor
{

    public void ProcessMessage()
    {
        ConvertReceivedMessage();
        SendToThirdParty();
        ReceiveResponse();
        ConvertResponseMessage();
        SendResponseToClient();
    }

    private void ConvertReceivedMessage()
    {
        //here I want to publish the performance counter value from the decorated class
    }
    private void SendToThirdParty()
    {
         //here I want to publish the performance counter value from the decorated class

    }
    private void ReceiveResponse()
    {
         //here I want to publish the performance counter value from the decorated class

    }
    private void ConvertResponseMessage()
    {
         //here I want to publish the performance counter value from the decorated class

    }

    private void SendResponseToClient()
    {
         //here I want to publish the performance counter value from the decorated class

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is perfomance counter feature?

Comment: Why not use composition, and just use the MessageProcessor class there? Then just call the ProcessMessage() method from the new class?

Comment: does your decorator just call `MessageProcessor.ProcessMessage` or does it inherit from `MessageProcessor`

Comment: Can the methods not be protected, with each method being overridden, do your performance counting, and calling the base class method? Not the ideal solution, but possibly an option.

Comment: My decorator inherits from MessageProcessor . I don't have the source code of the MessageProcessor  class to change the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of IProcessor objects instead of a bunch of methods. Going this way you are able to add/skip/change call order. In your IProcessor declare Process(PerformanceContext context) method and implement PerformanceContext class to exchange some values like StartTime, NumberOfCalls etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Denis, I asked my vendor to provide the class in the way you proposed. I also did a small POC based on your suggestion and it worked.